# Remove Permissions to Shared Mailboxes in Exchange 2016 for Multiple/all users who have access to that mailbox

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2016

Is it possible to achieve this for multiple users CSV import etc.

I have used the following for individual accounts before but not sure how to apply it to multiple accounts

```
Remove-MailboxPermission -Identity Sharedmailbox -User USER -AccessRights FullAccess,SendAs,ExternalAccount,DeleteItem,ReadPermission,ChangePermission,ChangeOwner -InheritanceType All
```

Also is there a way to revert this if needed so basically adding all the same users with a Script

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you check my answer below?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get all permission first with `Get-Mailboxpermission` command.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-mailboxpermission?view=exchange-ps

After it, you can iterate through the collection with a foreach. And call the `Remove-MailboxPermission` cmdlet with the needed attributes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/remove-mailboxpermission?view=exchange-ps

Something like this (sidenote: I can’t test it from phone but I will check it tomorrow from pc):

```
$user = john@contoso.com
$permissions = Get-MailboxPermission -Identity $user
foreach($permission in $permissions) {
  Remove-MailboxPermission -Identity $user -User $permission.User -AccessRights $permission.ExtendedRights -InheritanceType All
}
```

---

Edit:
Or you can check this site and try the scripts on it. https://morgantechspace.com/2019/11/remove-mailbox-permissions-using-powershell.html